# unable to perform image recognition in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I am trying to compare two images with available npms in protractor. Tried with "image-diff" npm and found no solution. when i tried with the given sample code in the npm it is not showing any result . Below is the sample code which i tried

```
imageDiff({
          actualImage: 'D:\\imageRecognition\\picA.png',
          expectedImage: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\picB.png',
          diffImage: 'D:\\imageRecognition\\result.png',

        }, function (err, imagesAreSame) {
          console.log("diffrence between images ================> "+ imagesAreSame);
        });
```

the parameter 'imagesAreSame' should return a boolean value whether the images are same or not but it is  not showing any effect. Can somebody help to get out of this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install image magick before image-diff? If so, could you be more specific about it "not showing any effect"?

Comment: Thanku for quick response TesterPhi..No i din install imageMagick, I thought like the 'image-diff' npm will do it internally. I am using 64bit windows machine, can you suggest to me which  file has to to be installed as there are so many .exe files with different pixel specifications.

Answer (score 1):

image-diff depends on ImageMagick. "Please install this before continuing." Is the advice they give. So I suggest following their advice.. In terms of the version to use...

Suggested version:
ImageMagick-6.9.3-4-Q16-x64-dll.exe - Win64 dynamic at 16 bits-per-pixel

Reason:
Its the highest resolution they support, if you want the highest accuracy this is the one to go for. Its also suitable for windows 64bit operating system. This is the system you are using

Comment: tried the same code after installing the 'imageMagick' suggested version still i dint find an solution. When i m trying to print the value of 'imagesAreSame', it is printing the value as 'undefined'. Is that related to callback function in the above specified code. Please give some a solution regarding these callabacks as i m new to using callback functions.